# Calculating SUM() of time values returns the time value as a string

Tags: php, datetime, doctrine, aggregate-functions

I have a query that returns the sum of all the "total" fields in my database table. The query:

```
public function findHoursTotal($user)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('h')
        ->where('h.user = :user')
        ->andWhere('h.date BETWEEN :start AND :end')
        ->select("SUM(h.total)")
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->setParameter('start', new \DateTime("midnight first day of this month"))
        ->setParameter('end', new \DateTime("Last day of this month"))
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

The query works like intended but I can't get the format right.

The `total` field is `TIME` and contains values such as:

```
01:24:00
01:00:00
```

The query will return the sum of this as 12400.

I tried the `DATE_FORMAT()` but this returns null:

```
->select("DATE_FORMAT(SUM(h.total), '%H:%:i%s')")
```

I tried to convert the string to a dateformat in my controller but php thinks the format is in seconds.

Does anyone know how to get the result from the query in H:i:s?

Comment: What rdbms are you using and what is the datatype of `h.total` column?

Comment: @SalmanA The datatype of h.total field is Time but the query returns a string and im using Phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot `SUM` the `time` value. But you can convert [`TIME_TO_SEC`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec), calculate sum of seconds, then convert [`SEC_TO_TIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time):

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(total)))
FROM h
WHERE ...
-- should give you something similar to 02:24:00
```

Comment: Thanks for the awnser. I am trying to get the function to work because i get this error: `Error: Expected known function, got 'SEC_TO_TIME'`

Comment: What database are you using? These functions are available in MySQL so should not be  problem. Also, this is the raw query. You will need to do something like `select("SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(h.total)))")`

Comment: Yes i tried the raw query in phpmyadmin and it works. Only Symofny doesn't reconize the function SEC_TO_TIME so im trying to figure it out.